# Combining Angle from AX12 Servo and data from Hokuyo Laser

Tags: ros, rviz, hokuyo-node, ax12

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Currently I am trying to generate a 3D map using the AX12 Servo and Hokuyo Laser. As of now I can control the AX12 Servo using the Dynamixel_Tutorials found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials) and can start up the Hokuyo Laser using the Hokuyo Laser Drivers (tutorials can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Tutorials)). How do I get the servo to integrate the angle into the laser scan data so when it is run through rviz it will create a 3D map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12347/combining-angle-from-ax12-servo-and-data-from-hokuyo-laser/) by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to look at the [laser_assembler](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler) package that provides nodes that listen to streams of scans and then assemble them into a larger 3D Cartesian coordinate (XYZ) point cloud.

We have pretty much the same setup on our robot - tilting Dynamixel motor with a Hokuyo laser attached to it. I have written a [node](http://code.google.com/p/ua-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/arrg/ua_controllers/wubble_actions/nodes/hokuyo_laser_action.py) that interfaces with [pr2_laser_snapshotter](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_arm_navigation/trunk/pr2_arm_navigation_perception/src/pr2_laser_snapshotter.cpp) node to get the cloud each time the laser does a full profile (goes up and down). There's nothing terribly complicated in both of those nodes, one just tells the other when it's at the beginning/end of profile and the other calls out to laser_assembler to get the cloud at that point in time. You can write your own node if you have different requirements.

Look at bottom of [this launch file](http://code.google.com/p/ua-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/arrg/ua_apps/wubble2_robot/launch/laser_perception.launch) for an example on how to launch these nodes.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to do this, you must set up some controller that will monitor the servo's position and [publish a transform](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) from the laser's frame to the base_link frame (or whatever frame you choose). Then, ROS will be able to easily run calculations based on where the laser is at any given time.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1